# LastPass to PasswordSafe

Tags: csv, passwords, lastpass

I'm migrating from LastPasss to PasswordSafe and i've been searching for a way to convert the CSV file exported from LastPass to PasswordSafe database but to no avail.
Does anyone have an idea on how to do this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's obviously no automated tool that can do this.

However, I've found the answer in this [thread](https://sourceforge.net/p/passwordsafe/discussion/134800/thread/447a9aa3/) and it worked like a charm.